# How can I make the first item in my *ngFor active by default (i.e. border-color of active item should be differnt from other items by deafult)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

> Currently, I'm working on the Angular 8 Application. And I wanted to
> make my first item of loop active by default. Active in the sense that its
> border-color got changed. To further clarify my question I've also
> attached a picture. In the below picture you can see that the first
> category is 'Chicken'. So it must be selected by default. Any Help would be very much appreciated.
> Thank You!

[image]

**My HTML**

```
        <div class="category-slider swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="margin-right: 100px;" *ngFor="let i = index; let category of brand_Categories">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="getSubCategories(category.CategoryId,category?.CategoryTitle)"
                 class="categories">
                 <div>
                <div class="icon text-custom-white bg-light-green" id="myDIV" (click)="toggle(i)" [ngClass]="(selectedID == i) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected' ">

                      <img
                      src="{{category?.CategoryImage || 'https://giftclubimagestorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/biryani.jpg'}}"
                      class="rounded-circle"
                      alt="{{category?.CategoryTitle || ''}}" class="imgrr">

                </div>
              </div>
                <span class="text-light-black cat-name">{{category?.CategoryTitle || ''}}</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hi, You could try setting the selectedID to 0 in ngOninit()

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working. Maybe you can please elaborate through code

Comment: Ohh thanks, Man. It worked. My bad I was making a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I tried out.

html

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
    <div class="item" [ngClass]="{'selected-item': selectedID == i}" (click)="selectItem(i)">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}
.selected-item {
    border: solid 2px green;
}
```

ts

```
public items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'];
public selectedID = 0;

selectItem(i){
  this.selectedID = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `first` variable provided in *ngFor context?

```html
<div *ngFor="let category of brand_Categories; let i = index; let first = first">
  <div [ngClass]="(selectedID == i || !selectedID && first) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected' ">
</div>
```

Optionally

```html
<div *ngFor="let category of brand_Categories; let i = index;>
  <div [ngClass]="(selectedID == i || !selectedID && i == 0) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected' ">
</div>
```

in addition consider setting the `selectedId` to zere in the Component.